# Cannot unmount USB o write on USB as normal user

Tags: usb, automount, udev, unmount

I have the following file of rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/

```
KERNEL!="sd[a-z]*", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"  
# Import FS infos  
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"  
# Get a label if present, otherwise specify one  
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="", ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_LABEL}"  
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="", ENV{dir_name}="usbhd-%k"  
# Global mount options  
ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="relatime"  
# Filesystem-specific mount options  
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="vfat|ntfs", ENV{mount_options}="$env{mount_options},utf8,gid=100,umask=002"  
# Mount the device  
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/dir", RUN+="/bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/dir"  
# Clean up after removal  
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /media/dir", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/dir"  
# Exit  
LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

The problem is that all the time I plug in the USB I have a message like that the USB is already mounted (/dev/sdb already mounted in /media/dir) and at unmount the user has no rights to unmount the USB. Also the normal user has no write permissions on the USB.

What can I change to be able to fix these issues?

Thank you.

Comment: Try: `sudo rm -r /media/*` without any USB-sticks.